# What's the probability of at least one of them will be depressed if their friendship suddenly ends?

Tags: probability

> In a community, everyone has $p(k)$ probability to have exactly $k$ friends. Everyone with less than $K$ friends is depressed. We pick out a pair of friends. What's the probability of at least one of them will be depressed if their friendship suddenly ends? Note: They could be depressed before the "break up".

One can be depressed if the number of his friends is $\leq K$, so it's probability is
$$P=\sum_{i=1}^{K} p(i)$$
So the answer is
$$2P=2\sum_{i=1}^{K} p(i)$$
Is this the right answer?

Comment: You need to subtract the probability that both people have $\le K$ friends. But I don't think the problem gives you enough information to compute this, since no information is given about the dependence among people.

Comment: @angryavian Why do I need to subtract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persons A and B are guaranteed to have at least one friend. If one of these persons is to be depressed after the breakup, at least one of them must have a number of friends between 1 and K. That probability is:

$$P(A)=P(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{K} p(i)$$

The probability of interest to us is

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=$$

$$2\sum_{i=1}^{K} p(i) - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{K} p(i)\right)^2$$

Comment: Should I calculate with the $p(0)$? Everyone should have at least 1 friend to be able to lose a friend.

Comment: You are right, I have re-arranged the proof.

Comment: Thank you, I see now why should I subtract the $P(A \cap B)$, and how to calculate it.

Comment: I was told that this solution is not good, because we are more likely to pick one of A's friendship if he has much more friends than B. But how could I include it in the probability?

Comment: @Oldboy You seem to have assumed independence when doing $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.